# Calculation of scaling factor

Tags: javascript

I've got multiple number values with a min and a max value. Assume the minimum value should be visualized by a 5px circle and the maximum value should be visualized by a 50px circle, I need to calculate a scaling factor for all other values.

```
50 / maxValue * value
```

...is not working well, because it does not consider the min value.

```
const array = [5, 20, 50, 100]
const min = 5 // => 5px
const max = 100 // => 50px
```

Comment: `(50-5) / (maxValue-minValue) * (value-minValue) + 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`d3-scale`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) does exactly this for you.

You just need to create a `scaleLinear`, define the `domain` (range of input values), and `range` (corresponding desired output values).

Have a look at the snippet below for an illustration:

```js
const array = [5, 20, 50, 100]
const min = 5 // => 5px
const max = 100 // => 50px

// define the scaling function
const size = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([5, 50])
    
   // call it for each value in the input array
array.forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val, Math.round(size(val)) + 'px')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-scale@3.2.0/dist/d3-scale.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the so called [Linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) method.

The following function takes 3 parameters:

- a: The starting value
- b: The destination value
- amount: The normal or actual value (percentage between 0 and 1) to control the Linear Interpolation

```js
function mix(a, b, amount) {
  return (1 - amount) * a + amount * b
}
```

Imagine a line from A to B and you put a circle on it:

A ----o--------------------------- B

- If your normal value is equal to 1 the circle will instantly switch from A to B.
- If your normal value is equal to 0 the circle will not move.
- The closer your normal is to 0 the smoother will be the interpolation.
- The closer your normal is to 1 the sharper will be the interpolation.

```js
const array = [5, 20, 50, 100]
const minpx = 5 // => 5px
const maxpx = 50 // => 50px
const min = Math.min(...array) // 5
const max = Math.max(...array) // 100

function mix(a, b, amount) {
  return (1 - amount) * a + amount * b
}

array.map(value => mix(minpx, maxpx, (value-min) / (max-min)))
// [ 5, 12.105263157894736, 26.31578947368421, 50 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [5, 20, 50, 100]
const minpx = 5 // => 5px
const maxpx = 50 // => 50px

let max = Math.max(...array)
let min = Math.min(...array)
// (x-min)/(max-min)   the ratio
// * (maxpx-minpx)     the new range
// + minpx             the new offset
let transform = x=>(x-min)/(max-min)*(maxpx-minpx)+minpx
console.log(array.map(transform))
```